# How to set the DIV attribute id in Appcelerator (mobileweb) when not using Alloy

Tags: appcelerator, mobile-website, appcelerator-titanium

I am using Appcelerator in a cross platform solution (iOS, Android, MobileWeb).  I want to be able to see id attributes for my UI elements in mobileweb.  I have seen examples of how to set the id using Alloy but I don't use Alloy, I script all my elements in JavaScript.

Can someone tell me the property I have to apply to a view to have the id set in the resulting DIV in html.

The following is an example view:

```
this.Viewer = Ti.UI.createScrollView(
{
    left:25,
    right:5,
    bottom:5,
    top: 0,
    width: this.App.Width - 40,
    height:  200,
    contentHeight: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    borderColor: "#333333",
    borderWidth: 3,
    horizontalWrap: false,
    layout:"vertical",
    scrollType: "vertical",
    scrollsToTop: true,
    showVerticalScrollIndicator: true,
    showHorizontalScrollIndicator: false,
    verticalBounce: false,
    visible: true,
    zIndex:100
});
```

and the resulting HTML

```
<div class="TiUIElement TiUIView TiLayoutsComposite" data-widget-id="Ti.UI.View:36" style="background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%; border-color: rgb(51, 51, 51); border-width: 2px; left: 5px; top: 90px; width: 507px; height: 626px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Titanium Mobile Web was designed to mimic the native iOS and Android platforms. Since iOS and Android do not have the concept of a DOM, there is no Titanium API to expose the DOM.

In other words, you're not suppose to be able to set an "id" on a `<div>`, or even know that the `<div>` exists.

However, you can do it if you absolutely need to. There is a property on all UI elements called `domNode`. This is ONLY available on Titanium Mobile Web. You need to case this out in order to run your app on iOS or Android.

```
var myButton = Ti.UI.createButton({ title: 'click me' });
if (Ti.Platform.name === 'mobileweb') {
    myButton.domNode.setAttribute('id', 'foo');
}
```

Pro tip: Titanium Mobile Web can't access a the browser's garbage collector, so if you remove a UI element, you must explicitly call the undocumented `destroy()` method so that events will be disconnected, DOM nodes will be destroy, and the state will be garbage collected.

```
myButton.destroy && myButton.destroy()
```

Comment: Barber your the man!  -- as he mentions this example, note that when you explicitly case out for MobileWeb you can put Any standard browser JavaScript into that statement. This includes references to the window and document objects etc

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to add an `id` property to your View creation function like this.

```
this.Viewer = Ti.UI.createScrollView(
{
    id: 'myView',   // <---- HERE IS YOUR ID
    name: 'myView', // <---- IF YOU NEED THE `NAME` ATTRIBUTE AS WELL
    left:25,
    right:5,
    bottom:5,
    top: 0,
    width: this.App.Width - 40,
    height:  200,
    contentHeight: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    borderColor: "#333333",
    borderWidth: 3,
    horizontalWrap: false,
    layout:"vertical",
    scrollType: "vertical",
    scrollsToTop: true,
    showVerticalScrollIndicator: true,
    showHorizontalScrollIndicator: false,
    verticalBounce: false,
    visible: true,
    zIndex:100
});
```

Comment: You would think that this is the answer, but it is not (or I am doing something wrong).  I added both an id and a name property and neither appear in the resulting HTML

Comment: So it seems custom properties don't make it to the HTML. Please check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.